# Check in which points is f differentiable.

Tags: analysis, banach-spaces

Check in which points is f differentiable:

$f: l_{ \Bbb R}^{ \infty} \ni x \rightarrow ||x||_{ \infty} \in \Bbb R$

I started with this:
$ \lim_{||h||_{\infty} \to 0} \frac{|f(x+h)-f(x)-L(h)|}{||h||_{ \infty}} =0 $

$ \lim_{||h||_{\infty} \to 0} \frac{| \ ||x+h||_{\infty}-||x||_{\infty}-L(h)|}{||h||_{ \infty}} =0 $

I have no idea what should i do next, please help me :)

Comment: What is $l^\infty_{\mathbb R}$? Do you mean $\ell^\infty(\mathbb N)$, the space space of real bounded sequences?

Comment: @YiorgosS.Smyrlis: I suspect this is just to clarify real scalars are being used. For instance, when I see $\ell^\infty$, I usually assume the entries are in $\mathbb{C}$.

Answer (score 2):

Here are some examples which should get you on the right track.

> Let $x = (5,5,1,2,1,2,1,2, \ldots)$. Note that $\|x\| = 5$ occurs in two distinct positions. Now, consider $g : \mathbb{R} \to \mathbb{R}$ given by $g(t) = \|x + (t,0,0,0, \ldots)\|$. You should find by direct calculation that $g$ is not differentiable at $t=0$. By writing $g$ as the composition of a differentiable function $\mathbb{R} \to \ell^\infty$ and $f : \ell^\infty \to \mathbb{R}$ and using the chain rule, you should be able to conclude that $f$ is not differentiable at $x$.

In a similar vein:

> Let $x = (5, 5-\frac{1}{2},5-\frac{1}{3},5-\frac{1}{4},5-\frac{1}{5},\ldots)$. Is $f$ differentiable at $x$?

You should come to suspect that, at a point $x$ where $f$ is differentiable, there is a special index $i$. The derivative of $f$ will need to be a bounded linear functional, can you think how to define one using the index $i$?